# Garage Band for Windows

Tags: windows, music

Is there any software like Garage Band but for windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for something to create primarily loop-based music, and maybe do some recording, take a look at [Sony Acid](http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/products/acidfamily.asp), [Ableton Live](http://www.ableton.com/products), and [Fruity Loops Studio](http://flstudio.image-line.com/documents/what.html).

There are other programs available. For more info, try searching for info on "digital audio workstations".

Comment: +1 for FL Studio.  I'm a Live user myself, but have much respect for FL... it's lean, easy to use, and has great out-of-the-box instruments.

Answer (score 0):

Not really the same like Garage Band, but you could try [SongSmith](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/songsmith/).

Also [this article](http://www.microsoft.com/athome/music/makemusic.aspx) might interest you.

Comment: "Microsoft, huh? So it's pretty easy to use?"  bwahahahahahaha http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3oGFogwcx-E