# GarageBand Alternative for Windows?

Tags: windows, music, garageband

Note: This question is similar to [92383](https://superuser.com/questions/92383/), but a) it doesn't have to be free and b) the accepted answer doesn't compare.

I got a USB-Midi Keyboard and I'm looking for a Software Sequencer. Nothing fancy, something like GarageBand, but for Windows. So it should emulate instruments, allow to add wav-files/loops, record vocals. If it supports VSTi, that would be a huge plus.

Prime Contender seems to be [Magix Music Maker](http://www.magix.com/us/music-maker/), but is the this only one? I'm looking something in the beginner/"prosumer" area, but I would hope that VSTi allows me to add instruments and effects later if I outgrow it.

Comment: I was kinda surprised to see Audacity as the replacement for GarageBand.  srsly?

Comment: A couple of recommendations here: http://superuser.com/questions/54191/garage-band-for-windows/54208#54208

Answer (score 3):

In addition to searching superuser, checkout kvraudio.com.  It is a great computer audio resource and has a database of searchable hosts.  This link shows all windows hosts that support VSTs:

http://www.kvraudio.com/get.php?mode=results&st=q&s=11

Answer (score 2):

[Cakewalk Music Creator 5](http://www.cakewalk.com/products/musiccreator/) is $35 or so.  I haven't used it, but I've heard good things about Cakewalk software.